# Docker-compose: Avoid docker containers being named with underscore?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

Rather pressing issue; My docker containers are being named by `docker-compose` with an underscore inbetween, f.e. `src_jira_1` despite the `docker-compose.yml` stating as such:

`services:
  jira:`

Is there a way to circumvent this? It makes communication in between containers on the default network not possible, because src_jira_1 is an invalid DNS name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can specify what will be the container name like that :

```
services:
    jira:
        container_name: myJIRA
```

Comment: I have this in my code and the "_1" still gets appended